# Recreate Az.Connect-AzAccount in c#

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, azure-api-management, azure-authentication

PowerShell has a great function in the Az.Accounts library - "Connect-AzAccount" - that allows me to authenticate against my Azure instance and publish APIM's easily.  I need to port the code over to c# and am unable to find an easy equivalent.

Has anyone found a straightforward way to do this?  The Azure world / libraries seem to be updating frequently, along with the many security aspects.  It's difficult to find a recent, relevant example.

My ultimate goal is to authenticate against Azure, then publish API's to the API Gateway.

The PowerShell code:

```bsh
$user = "account@domain.com"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password goes here" -AsPlainText -Force

$azAccount = @{
    subscription = "subscription-guid-goes-here"
    credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $user,$password
}

Connect-AzAccount @azAccount
```

Comment: There is a [.NET Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/?view=azure-dotnet) for the Azure REST API, but I've never used it, so can't say if it is a viable option here.  You could just save the code to a script and execute it indirectly from C# by passing it to `PowerShell.exe`.  Alternatively, you can call PowerShell more directly using the [PowerShell Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=pscore-6.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, [Azure Management Library for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net) can only be used to manage partial Azure resources. However, Azure API Management is not included.

So, I suggest you use [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) to manage your resources.

As Azure REST APi is protected under Azure AD. So, the first step is to acquire an accesstoken for authentication.

Here is a sample by using **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory** package

```
static string GetToken()
{
    string tenantId = "your tenant id or name, for example: hanxia.onmicrosoft.com";
    string clientId = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2"; // it is a public client for every tenant. 
    string resource = "https://management.core.windows.net/";
    string username = "user name, jack@hanxia.onmicrosoft.com";
    string password = "password, D******";

    var upc = new UserPasswordCredential(username, password);
    var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId);
    AuthenticationResult result = context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, upc).Result;
    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

After that, you can call Azure REST API along with adding authorization header. Here is a POST request sample:

```
public static string postRequest(string url, string access_token, string data)
{
    byte[] buffer = null;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "post";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
    //request.Headers.Add("other header", "it's value");
    if (data != null)
        buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    else
        buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("");
    request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
    request.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        return response.StatusCode + " " + reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can suggest him to use pre-release package.  But i don't.

Comment: right, that's the reason for not even mentioning it. makes sense. better to recreate the SDK. lol

Answer (score 0):

the existing answer is a bit odd, its linking some old depreciated library. [Official library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net) supports ["managing" Api Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.apimanagement?view=azure-dotnet). That would be the preferred way of managing Azure resources with C# and you dont have to recreate anything.